# Unlist nested column in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a nested data frame with `dplyr` for writing some JSON, but I'm having some issues with getting my desired output. Some example code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), "level_1" = c("C", "C", "D", 
             "D"),  "values" = c(1,1,2,2), "other_values" = c(1,2,3,4))

df <- df %>% group_by(ID, values) %>% nest() %>% group_by(ID) %>% nest()
```

This gives me an output of

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID    data            
  <fct> <list>          
1 A     <tibble [2 x 2]>
2 B     <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

I'm trying to remove the `list` type of the `data` column, so instead the output would read more like

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID    data            
  <fct> <chr>          
1 A     <tibble [2 x 2]>
2 B     <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

Is it even possible to store a tibble as an element of a tibble that's not contained in a list? Most things that I've tried have thrown errors that suggest this is the case.

Actual toJSON output:

```
[{
        "ID": "A",
        "data": [{
            "values": 1,
            "data": [{
                    "level_1": "C",
                    "other_values": 1
                },
                {
                    "level_1": "C",
                    "other_values": 2
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "ID": "B",
        "data": [{
            "values": 2,
            "data": [{
                    "level_1": "D",
                    "other_values": 3
                },
                {
                    "level_1": "D",
                    "other_values": 4
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Desired toJSON output:

```
[{
        "ID": "A",
        "data": {
            "values": 1,
            "data": [{
                    "level_1": "C",
                    "other_values": 1
                },
                {
                    "level_1": "C",
                    "other_values": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "ID": "B",
        "data": {
            "values": 2,
            "data": [{
                    "level_1": "D",
                    "other_values": 3
                },
                {
                    "level_1": "D",
                    "other_values": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: A set of data.frames joined together has to be a `list` as far as I know. I'm not really understanding how you are envisioning them ending up joined as a character vector. Can you give more info on the JSON you expect to write out from the tibble?

Comment: Added a JSON example. Honestly the output was something I saw in a random slide deck while searching around for solutions. Maybe there's a different approach entirely I should take?

Comment: I don't know that your desired json output will help, since does not correlate at all. Does `jsonlite::toJSON(df)` provide something useful?

Comment: That should be a better example